# Python nested loop comparing two lists and updating a dictionary

Tags: python, performance, list, compare

This code works as expected but takes up a lot of memory and takes vastly longer to run than any other part of my code.

```
def function(input1, input2):
    mapping = []
    for item in input1:
        risks = {"A":0, "B":0, "C":0, "D":0, "E":0}
        temp = []
        for row in input2:
            if item in row[0]:
                for key in risks.keys():
                    if row[1] == key:
                        risks[key] += 1
        temp.append(item)
        for key in risks.keys():
            temp.append(risks[key])
        mapping.append(temp)
    return mapping
```

I'm hoping to find a more efficient way to do this and with far less memory. `input1` is a list of unique strings and `input2` is a list of tuples that are not unique. There has got to be a better way to do this.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you explain (in words) what you function is supposed to do?

Comment: Or provide some kind of example input and output…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First some test data:

```
import random

input1 = list(range(1000))
input2 = [
    ([random.randint(0, 1000) for _ in range(100)], random.choice("ABCDE"))
    for _ in range(10000)
]
```

Then my new function:

```
def newfunction(input1, input2):
    input1_map = {i: dict.fromkeys("ABCDE", 0) for i in input1}

    for row in input2:
        for i1 in set(row[0]):
            try:
                input1_map[i1][row[1]] += 1
            except KeyError:
                pass

    return [[i] + list(input1_map[i].values()) for i in input1]
```

This is of depth 2, not 3, so ends up being a lot faster for large inputs.

1. If `row[0]` does not contain duplicates, change `set(row[0])` to just `row[0]`.
2. If the `try` should never fail, remove it.
3. Choose better variable names. I don't know what things represent so my names here are pretty bad.
4. The last statement could be micro-optimised away if speed is too much of a concern, but I wouldn't expect it would matter much.
5. The `list(input1_map[i].values())` is non-deterministic. Think about that.

For reference, here's the old version:

```
def function(input1, input2):
    mapping = []
    for item in input1:
        risks = {"A":0, "B":0, "C":0, "D":0, "E":0}
        temp = []
        for row in input2:
            if item in row[0]:
                for key in risks.keys():
                    if row[1] == key:
                        risks[key] += 1
        temp.append(item)
        for key in risks.keys():
            temp.append(risks[key])
        mapping.append(temp)
    return mapping
```

And it passes my test:

```
function(input1, input2) == newfunction(input1, input2)
#>>> True
```